# Why is my media query not working with MUI Components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Need help in reactjs, i want to change the flex direction when i reached the breakpoint of md or tablet screens, Will also add breakpoints for desktop screens. Why is my media query not working?

````
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import * as React from "react";
import  {styled} from "@mui/material/styles";

function test() { 
const RD = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
    [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
      flexDirection: "row-reverse",
    },
  }));

  return (
    <RD>
      <Container
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          mt: 12,
          backgroundColor: "#FFFBEC",
          paddingTop: 5,
          paddingBottom: 5,
        }}
      >
        <Box sx={{}}>
          <Typography
            sx={{
              fontSize: 25,
            }}
          >
            Hello world
          </Typography>

          <Typography>
            World Hello
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </RD>
  );
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your media query was applied to the **RD** component, not the target `<Container />` component. It's `<Container />` that has *flex* assigned to the *display* property.

Your media query just needed a little update, plus a **className** (e.g. *contained*) was added to find the `<Container />` tag:

```js
  const RD = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
    [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
      ['& .contained']: {
        flexDirection: "row-reverse",
      }
    },
  }));
```

```js
      <Container
        className="contained"
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          mt: 12,
          backgroundColor: "#FFFBEC",
          paddingTop: 5,
          paddingBottom: 5,
        }}
      >
```

If you want to avoid using a static, manually-provided className, you could wrap the `<Container />` component into another *styled()* call to generate a dynamic className. For example:

```js
    const StyledContainer = styled( ({className, ...props}) => (
        <Container className={className}>
          ...
        </Container>
    ),
    {
        label: 'StyledContainerClassNameSuffix'
    } )( ({theme, ...props}) => {
        return {
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          mt: 12,
          backgroundColor: "#FFFBEC",
          paddingTop: 5,
          paddingBottom: 5,
        }
    });
```

The *StyledContainer*'s className will end up looking something like:
css-5gnohv-StyledContainerClassNameSuffix